# Is there an easy way to list out all sklearn implementations that take sparse training input?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As opposed to just trying them with sparse input and getting an error.
Something like the listing of classifiers shown here:
[AdaBoostClassifier with different base learners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306416/adaboostclassifier-with-different-base-learners)

Comment: You can use a similar method and ``try`` to fit them with sparse data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, answering my own question for posterity, adapting original post with `try` as suggested by andreas. Def should have thought of that.

```
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators
import numpy as np
import random
y = np.array([random.randrange(0,2) for i in xrange(1000)])
X = csc_matrix(np.array([[random.randrange(0,2) for i in xrange(1000)], 
                         [random.randrange(0,2) for i in xrange(1000)], 
                         [random.randrange(0,2) for i in xrange(1000)]])).T
for name, Clf in all_estimators(type_filter='classifier'):
    try:
        clf = Clf()
        clf.fit(X,y)
        print name
    except:
        pass
```

which gave this list:

```
BernoulliNB
DummyClassifier
KNeighborsClassifier
LabelPropagation
LabelSpreading
LinearSVC
LogisticRegression
MultinomialNB
NearestCentroid
NuSVC
PassiveAggressiveClassifier
Perceptron
RadiusNeighborsClassifier
RidgeClassifier
RidgeClassifierCV
SGDClassifier
SVC
```

I know this is quick and dirty and misses any that fail for errors other than `TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.`, and just so everyone knows how conscientious I am, the only one that fails for some other reason is `EllipticEnvelope`. I checked. :) Also, the non-tree based ensemble methods like `BaggingClassifier` and `AdaBoostClassifier` can take sparse input if you change the base_estimator from the default to one that can take sparse input and has all the necessary methods/attributes and you use a sparse representation that can be indexed (`csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix`).