# AdaBoostClassifier with algorithm='SAMME.R' requires. But I already add algorithm='SAMME.R'

Tags: python, svm, adaboost

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import sys
#import warnings
#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.isna().sum()
df = df.fillna(0)

X = df[['salary', 'to_messages', 'deferral_payments', 'total_payments', 'exercised_stock_options', 'bonus', 'restricted_stock', 'shared_receipt_with_poi', 'restricted_stock_deferred', 'total_stock_value', 'expenses', 'loan_advances', 'from_messages', 'other', 'from_this_person_to_poi', 'director_fees', 'deferred_income', 'long_term_incentive', 'from_poi_to_this_person']]
y = df[['poi']]

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.35,random_state = 42)

clf_SVM = SVC(probability=False, kernel='linear')
clf_adaboost_boostAcc = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=20, algorithm='SAMME.R',base_estimator=clf_SVM,learning_rate=1)

model_adaboost_boostAcc = clf_adaboost_boostAcc.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

the problem line in the last line, I try to do adaboost but it say:

**TypeError: AdaBoostClassifier with algorithm='SAMME.R' requires that the weak learner supports the calculation of class probabilities with a predict_proba method.
Please change the base estimator or set algorithm='SAMME' instead.**

What do I need to do to fix this bug? I do following this guide: [adaboost+svc](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/adaboost-classifier-python?utm_source=google&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_campaignid=19589720824&utm_adgroupid=143216588537&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=671350460579&utm_targetid=dsa-1947282172981&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1012728&utm_content=dsa%7Epage%7Ecommunity-tuto&utm_campaign=230119_1-sea%7Edsa%7Etofu_2-b2c_3-row-p2_4-prc_5-na_6-na_7-le_8-pdsh-go_9-na_10-na_11-na&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1aOpBhCOARIsACXYv-dx3voRRxbQXm3ulYlcwR0rWh-z23d3jjuOdgnBqva8cpDNrsOgwocaAvMIEALw_wcB)
+if possible, is there a way to decrease time of training with svc? (I already try with StandardScaler and OneVsRestClassifier. It still take 4 hours with no result come out)

Answer (score 1):

In the [AdaBoostClassifier document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html), it is said "estimator must support calculation of class probabilities."

So, we change the `probability` parameter in `clf_SVM`.

```py
clf_SVM = SVC(probability=True, kernel='linear')
```

You can read some of the answers on the links below about how to decrease time of SVC training.
[Making SVM run faster in python - scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681373/making-svm-run-faster-in-python)
[SVM using scikit learn runs endlessly](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/989/svm-using-scikit-learn-runs-endlessly-and-never-completes-execution)

Comment: I got this following error: ValueError: NoneType doesn't support sample_weight.

Comment: Are you using the same code? Because it worked when I did it.

Comment: yes I use the same code, the error appear when I change probability=True

Comment: Hmm...It worked on my side. Maybe an answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107205/sklearn-ensemble-adaboostclassifier-cannot-accecpt-svm-as-base-estimator) may help. ‍♀️