# AdaBoostClassifier and the 'SAMME.R’ Algorithm

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, adaboost

It takes a while to get to the actual question, so please bear with me. [The AdaBoost documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) states that it " is a meta-estimator that begins by fitting a classifier on the original dataset and then fits additional copies of the classifier on the same dataset but where the weights of incorrectly classified instances are adjusted". To do that, one of the required paramenters is `base_estimator`. For the `base_estimator` to be useable with `AdaBoostClassifer`, "support for sample weighting is required".

So my first issue was - which classifiers provide support for sample weighting? I did some research, and, fortunately, [someone smarter than me had the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18323552/9448090).  Somewhat updated, it works thus: by running

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators 

print(all_estimators(type_filter='classifier'))
```

you get a list of all classifiers (turns out there are 31 of them!). Then, if you run

```
import inspect

for name, clf in all_estimators(type_filter='classifier'):
    if 'sample_weight' in inspect.getfullargspec(clf().fit)[0]:
        print(name)
```

you can get the list of all classifiers which provide support for sample weighting (21 of them, for the curious).

So far so good. But now we have to deal with another  `AdaBoostClassifer` parameter, namely `algorithm`. You have two options: `{‘SAMME’, ‘SAMME.R’}, optional (default=’SAMME.R’)`. We're told that to "use the SAMME.R real boosting algorithm  `base_estimator` must support calculation of class probabilities". And this is where I got stuck. Searching online, I can only find two classifiers used with ‘SAMME.R’ as an argument for `algorithm`: `DecisionTreeClassifier` (which is the default) and `RandomForestClassifier`.

So here's the question - which other classifiers from the 21 which are compatible with `AdaBoostClassifer` offer support for the calculation of class probablities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure that when the documentation refers to "must support calculation of class probabilities" they mean that there is a `predict_proba` method.

This is the method that many classifiers use to return the probabilities for each class given an observation. With that understanding you just need to check for classifiers that have the `predict_proba` method:

```
for name, clf in all_estimators(type_filter='classifier'):
    if hasattr(clf, 'predict_proba'):
        print(clf, name)

<class 'sklearn.ensemble.weight_boosting.AdaBoostClassifier'> AdaBoostClassifier

<class 'sklearn.ensemble.bagging.BaggingClassifier'> BaggingClassifier
<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB'> BernoulliNB
<class 'sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV'> CalibratedClassifierCV
<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.ComplementNB'> ComplementNB
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier'> DecisionTreeClassifier
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier'> ExtraTreeClassifier
<class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.ExtraTreesClassifier'> ExtraTreesClassifier
<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB'> GaussianNB
<class 'sklearn.gaussian_process.gpc.GaussianProcessClassifier'> GaussianProcess
Classifier
<class 'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting.GradientBoostingClassifier'> GradientBoosti
ngClassifier
<class 'sklearn.neighbors.classification.KNeighborsClassifier'> KNeighborsClassifier
<class 'sklearn.semi_supervised.label_propagation.LabelPropagation'> LabelPropagation
<class 'sklearn.semi_supervised.label_propagation.LabelSpreading'> LabelSpreading
<class 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis'> LinearDiscriminantA
nalysis
<class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'> LogisticRegression
<class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegressionCV'> LogisticRegressionCV
<class 'sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron.MLPClassifier'> MLPClassifier
<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB'> MultinomialNB
<class 'sklearn.svm.classes.NuSVC'> NuSVC
<class 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis'> QuadraticDiscrim
inantAnalysis
<class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestClassifier'> RandomForestClassifier
<class 'sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient.SGDClassifier'> SGDClassifier
<class 'sklearn.svm.classes.SVC'> SVC
```

So you end up with 24 of the 31 classifiers as being potential options for `base_estimator` in `AdaBoostClassifier`.

The error returned from using an improper classifier as `base_estimator` is also quite helpful in this regard.

> TypeError: AdaBoostClassifier with algorithm='SAMME.R' requires that the weak learner
>   supports the calculation of class probabilities with a predict_proba method.
>   Please change the base estimator or set algorithm='SAMME' instead.

As you can see the error specifically points you towards classes with the `predict_proba` method.

Comment: Great answer - and nice catch with the error! Only one comment - you say: "you end up with 24 of the 31 classifiers as being potential options for `base_estimator` in `AdaBoostClassifier`" - these 24 classifiers support **class probabilities**; but ABC also requires support of **sample weighting**. So, among the 31 classifiers - the number supporting **both** requirements is (drum roll!) - 17!

Comment: Is there any documentation about how to implement these methods for a natively non-accepted classifier, in order to make it work?